# How to change circle radius using slider in openlayer

Tags: openlayers

Need to change circle radius from slider. The radius is change but circle is not change its remain constant.

Please find below code.

```js
options = {
    div: "map",
    zoom: 2,
    center: [0, 0],
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM()
    ]
};
map = new OpenLayers.Map(options);
vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector();
map.addLayer(vector);


var point1 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(0,0);
var point2 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(1000000, 1000000);
var point3 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(2000000, 2000000);
var radius = $( "#amount" ).val();
 var mycircle = OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon(point2,radius,40,0);
     var featurecircle = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(mycircle);
     


// var selected_polygon_style = {
//     strokeWidth: 5,
//     strokeColor: '#ff0000'
//     // add more styling key/value pairs as your need
// };

// featurecircle.style = selected_polygon_style;

marker1 = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point1, null, {
    externalGraphic: "marker.png",
    graphicWidth: 32,
    graphicHeight: 32,
    fillOpacity: 1,
});
marker1.style = { display: 'none' };

marker2 = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point2, null, {
    externalGraphic: "marker.png",
    graphicWidth: 32,
    graphicHeight: 32,
    fillOpacity: 1
});

marker3 = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point3, null, {
    externalGraphic: "marker.png",
    graphicWidth: 32,
    graphicHeight: 32,
    fillOpacity: 1
});
vector.addFeatures([marker1, marker2, marker3, featurecircle]);



$( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
      range: "max",
      min: 1000000,
      max: 3000000,
      value: 1000000,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
         radius =  $( "#amount" ).val();

     
var mycircle = OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon
(
    point2,
    radius,
    40,
    0
);

var featurecircle = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(mycircle);

vector.removeFeatures(featurecircle);
vector.addFeatures(featurecircle);
         console.log(radius);

      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
$( radius ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding:5px;
    margin:0px;
}
#map {
    height:90%;
    width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.16.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>


<p>
  <label for="amount">Minimum number</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" value="1000000"  style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="slider-range-max"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

```
options = {
div: "map",
zoom: 2,
center: [0, 0],
layers: [
    new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM()
]
};
map = new OpenLayers.Map(options);
vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector();
map.addLayer(vector);


var point1 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(0,0);
var point2 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(1000000, 1000000);
var radius = $( "#amount" ).val();
var mycircle = OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon
(
    point2,
    radius,
    40,
    0
);

var featurecircle = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(mycircle);

marker1 = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point1, null, {
    externalGraphic: "marker.png",
    graphicWidth: 32,
    graphicHeight: 32,
    fillOpacity: 1
});

marker2 = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point2, null, {
    externalGraphic: "marker.png",
    graphicWidth: 32,
    graphicHeight: 32,
    fillOpacity: 1
});

vector.addFeatures([marker1, marker2, featurecircle]);

$( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
      range: "max",
      min: 1000000,
      max: 3000000,
      value: 1000000,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
         radius =  $( "#amount" ).val();
         console.log(radius);
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
radius =  $( "#amount" ).val();
```

[image: Slider adding multiple circles required to change one circle radius only]

Comment: Added the Running code snipeet - Slider is creating multiple circles need one circle and change radius with slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the circle feature and add it again to the vector layer.

Try adding these lines inside the slide function

```
vector.removeFeatures([featurecircle]);
var mycircle = OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon
(
    point2,
    radius,
    40,
    0
);

featurecircle = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(mycircle);
vector.addFeatures([featurecircle]);
```

Comment: Thanks But its creating multiple circles on slider event I need to change radius of one circle only- http://jsfiddle.net/zLjae81b/12/

Comment: I edited the answer. I think the problem is with removeFeatures, that needs an array as arguments. Try changing vector.removeFeatures(featurecirlce) with vector.removeFeatures([featurecircle])

Comment: Changed with vector.removeFeatures([featurecircle]).......Giving error Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: Added the screenshot its created multiple circles need to change one circle radius only - jsfiddle.net/zLjae81b/12

Comment: Added the Running code snipeet - Slider is creating multiple circles need one circle and change radius with slider

Comment: I've edited the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zLjae81b/18/ and updated the answer. It's working as expected now.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I am trying to convert this using openlayer 3. But there are lot of changes there are no marker in openlayer 3.. can any body suggest how to change this working example jsfiddle.net/zLjae81b/18 (something like  ol.Style.Icon)